# Using class extends instead of util.inherits

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

Instead of using:

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Clock = function Clock() {
  this._started = false;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
};

inherits(Clock, EventEmitter);

Clock.prototype.start = function start() {};
```

Using class extends is much cleaner imho:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class Clock extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.super_ = EventEmitter;
    this._started = false;
  }

  start() {}
}
```

I've added this.super_ = EventEmitter to the constructor, just because util.inherits is doing the same thing (ctor.super_ = superCtor;). I tried without it, and it looks it works without as well.

Now my question: is super_ property necessary, is it used by Node somehow? Or is there any problem using ES6 class extends instead of "Node's way" of inheritance with util.inherits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not a property used by `nodejs`, this is just an additional convenience added by the `util`.

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/util.markdown#utilinheritsconstructor-superconstructor